# Abort the channel entry publish process?

Tags: channel-entries, add-on-development

I am working on an extension that takes some entry data (from the control panel) and performs some tasks with it, just prior to insert/update. I am currently using the "entry_submission_end" hook to accomplish this. However, I would like to abort the entry submission/update process if my extension tasks are not completed successfully. It doesn't look like the "entry_submission_end" hook provides the

```
if (ee()->extensions->end_script === TRUE) return;
```

code to do this. What hook can I use to accomplish this? Thanks.

--Garrett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that hook does check for `end_script` - it just happens inside the `trigger_hook()` method.

However, if you want to bail out of an insert/update when your custom tasks are not completed, then you need to use something earlier than `entry_submission_end` (it's too late at that point, the entry has already been submitted).

I'd suggest either `entry_submission_start` or `entry_submission_ready`.

And be sure to redirect the user after you set `ee()->extensions->end_script` to `TRUE`, lest they end up at the WSOD!