# Add custom validation to Content_publish form

Tags: control-panel, module, extension, validation

In our system, entries are created from the Control Panel, and one of our custom entries needs more complicated validation rules.

Basically, depending on the status of the submitted entry, we need to determine whether other fields are required, validate the submission based on that and then show errors as per normal validation rules.

I've looked into getting access to the data from the `entry_submission_ready` hook and setting the errors via `ee()->form_validation->_error_array['foo'] = 'bar'`, but this hook is called after validation has already completed and passed.

Ideally I would prefer not having to rewrite any core code, though I am willing to override `Content_publish` if this can be done cleanly from a module/extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong hook. Try using [entry_submission_start](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/#entry-submission-start) and/or [publish_form_entry_data](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/content_publish/index.html#publish-form-entry-data)

Update:

- [Abort the channel entry publish process?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10411/abort-the-channel-entry-publish-process)
- [Head-scratcher: manipulating new/updated entries after submission](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/169717/)

Comment: Thanks Peter. Based on what I can see, `entry_submission_start` is called after validation in Content_publish, and is only passed `$channel_id`. `publish_form_entry_data` looks promising though, I'll look into it when I next get a chance.

Comment: It is 'technically', but not before the entry is saved, so still time to validate and abort if need be. Added to links for references.

Comment: Definitely the way to go. Solution is to implement the `entry_submission_start` hook, source the unprocessed submission data from `ee()->api_channel_entries->data` and add errors to `ee()->api_channel_entries->errors` using the element name / field name as the key. Errors are then associated correctly with the form elements, and everything looks nice. Thanks!